# WooCommerce API - Issue Creating Subscription with Mollie Payment Method for Auto Renewal

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm working on creating a subscription in WooCommerce through their API. While I'm able to successfully create the subscription and have also created a customer in Mollie with a mandate, I'm facing an issue where the subscription doesn't seem to have the correct payment method for auto-renewal.

#### Objective:

I want the subscription to have the correct payment method and support auto-renewal using the Mollie payment gateway.

Here's the code snippet I use to create the subscription:

```
const updatedSubscriptionData = {
  customer_id: customerId,
  status: 'active',
  billing_period: 'month',
  billing_interval: 3,
  ...subscriptionData,
  billing: {
    ...customerData.billingAddress,
  },
  shipping: {
    ...customerData.shippingAddress,
  },
  start_date: fullStartDate,
  payment_method: 'mollie_wc_gateway_directdebit',
};

const subscriptionResponse = await WooCommerce.post('subscriptions', updatedSubscriptionData);
```

##### Issue:

The subscription is created without any errors, but it doesn't seem to have the correct payment method set up for Mollie, and it doesn't auto-renew.

##### Attempts:

I've ensured that the customer has a mandate in Mollie and tried different variations of the payment_method field, but I'm unsure if 'mollie_wc_gateway_directdebit' is the correct value or if there's an additional step required.

Does anyone have any insights on how to correctly set up the payment method for auto-renewal using Mollie in WooCommerce through the API?